# git host key verification failed

Tags: git, ssh, yarn

0

если в консоли выполнить

```
git clone ssh://git@repo.trk.com:10022/fsas/modules.git
```

То клонирование происходит.

А когда в package.json добавляю зависимость

```
"modules": "git+ssh://git@repo.trk.com:10022/fsas/modules.git",
```

То выводит

```
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@repo.trk.com:10022/fsas/modules.git
Directory: /home/manking/Документы/it/inetpub/fsas
Output:
HOST key verification failed.
fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.
```

Используется gitlab. Внешний ключ ssh уже добавлен в gitlab.

Comment: *То выводит* — кто выводит?

Comment: консоль при команде yarn install

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополняйте само тело вопрос уточнениями (кнопка "править")